# ServiceResponseException: There are no public folder servers available

Tags: c#, api, exchangewebservices, managed, public-folders

I have been doing C# application which can access Public Folders through Exchange Web Services Managed API.

But there is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException which says **There are no public folder servers available.**

My public folders will be like this.

Folder 1 --> Subfolder1 | Subfolder2 | Subfolder3

Folder 2 --> Subfolder1 | Subfolder2

Folder 3

Folder 4 --> Subfolder1

The exception throws when the application access to **Folder 2**.
The application can access Folder 1 and display all 3 subfolders.

Exception throws here:
    Folder parentFolder = Folder.Bind(folderID, foldView.PropertySet);

I have tried recursive traversal and other possible ways. But problem still remains.
Please help me! I will be very very grateful for your guidance

Comment: Can you provide version information? Which versions of Exchange exhibit this behavior? Is this Exchange Online? Can you show us the XML?

Comment: When I checked the Exchange versions, I found two versions for Public Folders: _Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 SP2_ and _Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP3_. And I used _Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.1_. Is it because of the version incompatibility?

Comment: It may be a version incompatibility. What Exchange version is the calling accounts mailbox?

Comment: This is an older post, but were you able to resolve? I'm seeing the same errors after upgrading Exchange from 2010 to 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because I did not set the credentials.
So please check if you have set the credentials.

```
exchangeService.Credential = new NetworkCredential("UserName","Pasword", "Domain");
```